# How to filter phone and other web links in WebView Android

Tags: android, webview, external

What i want is to keep links in the web view as long as they are part of the site, but external links should launch into an external web browser. Also on the site i have phone link's with tel:555-323-2323 if i use the code below the phone number work and launch the phone app but external links are not working.

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        if (url.contains("tel:")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        } else {
            return true;
        } 
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason things are not working is because you have an if-else and both branches return true.  All code after the else statement is unreachable.  Remove the else statement or change that logic.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove first statement (`view.loadUrl(url)`).
- Remove `else` part of first condition.

Your code will look something like this :

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.contains("tel:")) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    } 
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com"))
        // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
        return false;

    // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs  
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)); startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution:

```
 @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.contains("tel:")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        }
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals(URL)) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
```